# Valor de hidden se confunden con php

Tags: php, input

Primero el código así se puede entender:

```html
<form method="post" action="publicar.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="cuerpoEnlace" id="cuerpo-en" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['secA']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="cuerpoComic" id="cuerpo-co" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['secB']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Publicar" id="publicar"><br>
</form>
```

El primer problema es que se visualiza el resultado (pierde la propiedad hidden).

Y además al final de cada impresión PHP sale el siguiente resultado: "> .

O sea me lee el signo > del cierre de PHP como el cierre del input.

No sé si fui claro, pero espero que alguien me pueda dar luz en este problema.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: El  formulario que pones en tu pregutna se ve correctamente, los campos hidden aparecen bien (o sea no se ven) y los values no muestran el carácter >

Comment: Hola Emmanuel, podrias compartir el codigo completo para tener mas contexto de tu problema?, saludos.

Comment: Por lo que leo es muy probable que tu código este imprimiendo un error y no lo ves, probablemente es por que las variables $_REQUEST['secA'] y $_REQUEST['secB'] no existen y como el error se esta imprimiendo dentro de un tag dentro de comillas no estas viendo el error, intenta ver el código fuente dentro del navegador.

Answer (score 0):

buenas tardes.

Estoy viendo tu codigo, y creo que seria mejor si utilizas una manera de concatenar lo valores que le queres pasar a los campos hidden.

```
<?php
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"publicar.php\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cuerpoEnlace\" id=\"cuerpo-en\" value=\"".$_REQUEST['secA']."\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cuerpoComic\" id=\"cuerpo-co\" value=\"".$_REQUEST['secB']."\">
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Publicar\" id=\"publicar\"><br>
</form>";
?>
```

Echo sirve para imprimir, eso puede ser lo que estás experimentando. De la manera en la que lo planteo imprimirá todo el formulario pasando los valores a los campos hidden.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar pasar los inputs a text y que sean con propiedad hidden

```
<form method="post" action="publicar.php" >
    <input type="text" name="cuerpoEnlace" id="cuerpo-en" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['secA']; ?>" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="cuerpoComic" id="cuerpo-co" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['secB']; ?>" hidden>
    <input type="submit" value="Publicar" id="publicar"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gente, les agradezco sus respuestas. Encontré la solución de la siguiente manera:

```html
<form method="post" action="admin/publicar.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="cuerpoEnlace" id="cuerpo-en" value="? echo $_REQUEST['secA']">
   <input type="hidden" name="cuerpoComic" id="cuerpo-co" value="? echo $_REQUEST['secB']">
   <input type="submit" value="Publicar" id="publicar"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Si era la solución que buscabas, acepta tu respuesta dándole al check aceptando tu respuesta y dejando la pregunta como contestada. También puedes comentar un poco el código para explicar a los demás lo que hace y lo que consigues con ello por si alguen tiene tu misma duda en un futuro.

Comment: Hola. No se como cerrar la pregunta que hice. Si entro con el mail me toma como alguien que contesta. Dw casualidad sabes como cerrarla.

Comment: Dale al check de tu respuesta. Debajo de las dos flechas con el cero en el medio de la parte izquierda de la respuesta. Así aceptas la respuesta como la que buscabas y la pregunta aparecerá contestada